# Prolog: "if then else", using cut

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

This is an easy question: I've seen this example in a Prolog text book.
It is implementing if-then-else using a cut.

```
if_then_else(P, Q, R) :- P, !, Q.
if_then_else(P, Q, R) :- R.
```

Can anyone explain what this program is doing, and why it is useful?

Comment: Before you start, if you don't know what the cut (`!`) operator does, I suggest you look it up and study some of those examples. Then you should do a `trace` at the Prolog prompt and run the predicate with some examples. Very simple examples would be to do queries like, `if_then_else(true, X = 3, X = 4).` and `if_then_else(false, X = 3, X = 4)` and see what the order of execution is. At a high level, it would do what you would expect any if-then-else construct to do in any language, and it's useful for the same reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing to note about this program that it is definitely **not** a nice relation.

For example, from a pure logic program, we expect to be able to derive **whether the condition had held** if we pass it the **outcome**. This is of course in contrast to procedural programming, where you first check a condition and everything else depends on the condition.

Also other properties are violated. For example, what happens if the condition actually *backtracks*? Suppose I want to see conclusions for *each* solution of the condition, not just the first one. Your code cuts away these additional solutions.

I would also like to use the relation in other cases, for example, suppose I want to detect *superfluous* if-then-else constructs in my code. These are solutions to queries similar to:

```
?- if_then_else(NoMatter, Same, Same).
```

If `if_then_else/3` were a pure relation, we could use it to answer such queries. As it is currently implemented, it yields **incorrect** results for such queries.

See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) and [**`if_/3`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/1613573) for more information.